# Delete list from the list matrix - Python

Tags: python, list

I created sorted matrix with ID/ Odometers/ Date. I really need to delete all list where 0 value is on the second position.
I prepared a function and loop but unfortunately I have still below error. I doubt that del [] method is used correctly ?

in zero_clear, if tablica[i][1] == 0: ****

```
tablica = [
            [ 
            [21091705,  0,'30.06.2019'],
            [21091705,  0,'29.06.2019'],
            [21091705,  653842,'29.06.2019'],
            [21091705,  641701,'28.06.2019'],
            [21091705,  642000,'27.06.2019'],
            [21091705,  0,'25.06.2019'],
            [21091705,  642030,'25.06.2019'],
            [21091705,  642030,'25.06.2019'],
            [21091705,  637030,'25.06.2019'],
            [21091705,  0,'25.06.2019'],
            [21091705,  0,'17.05.2019'],
            [21091705,  641256,'25.06.2019']
            ],
            [
            [21091703,  487000,'30.06.2019'],
            [21091703,  461524,'29.06.2019'],
            [21091703,  0,'29.06.2019'],
            [21091703,  0,'28.06.2019'],
            [21091703,  427701,'28.06.2019'],
            [21091703,  429000,'27.06.2019']
            ],
            [
            [21091701,  421077,'30.06.2019'],
            [21091701,  453777,'29.06.2019'],
            [21091701,  0,'29.06.2019'],
            [21091701,  427701,'28.06.2019'],
            [21091701,  433123,'27.06.2019']
            ],
            [
            [21091704,  491000,'30.06.2019'],
            [21091704,  0,'29.06.2019'],
            [21091704,  474542,'29.06.2019'],
            [21091704,  427701,'28.06.2019'],
            [21091704,  427701,'28.06.2019'],
            [21091704,  0,'27.06.2019']
            ]
            ]

def zero_clear(tablica):

    for i in range(len(tablica)):

        if tablica[i][1] == 0:
            del tablica[i]

    return tablica

for item in tablica:
    zero_clear(item)
```

Comment: Try `tablica.remove(tablica[i])`

Comment: it does not work. The same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you remove elements from your `tablica` list elements while you are iterating (using `for` loop) you are ending to jump the next element for every element deleted, to fix the issue you can use a `while` loop or create a new list:

**1) using `while` loop**

```
def zero_clear(tablica):
    i = 0
    while i < len(tablica):
        if tablica[i][1] == 0:
            del tablica[i]
        else:
            i += 1

for item in tablica:
    zero_clear(item)
```

**2) creating a new list**

```
def zero_clear(tablica):

    new_list = []

    for l in tablica:
        if l[1] != 0:
            new_list.append(l)

    return new_list




for item in tablica:
    item[:] = zero_clear(item)
```

or  creating a new elemen by using list comprehension:

```
for item in tablica:
    item[:] = [l for l in item if l[1] != 0]
```

or creating a completely new list using list comprehension:

```
tablica = [[l for l in item if l[1] != 0] for item in tablica]
```

output:

```
[[[21091705, 653842, '29.06.2019'],
  [21091705, 641701, '28.06.2019'],
  [21091705, 642000, '27.06.2019'],
  [21091705, 642030, '25.06.2019'],
  [21091705, 642030, '25.06.2019'],
  [21091705, 637030, '25.06.2019'],
  [21091705, 641256, '25.06.2019']],
 [[21091703, 487000, '30.06.2019'],
  [21091703, 461524, '29.06.2019'],
  [21091703, 427701, '28.06.2019'],
  [21091703, 429000, '27.06.2019']],
 [[21091701, 421077, '30.06.2019'],
  [21091701, 453777, '29.06.2019'],
  [21091701, 427701, '28.06.2019'],
  [21091701, 433123, '27.06.2019']],
 [[21091704, 491000, '30.06.2019'],
  [21091704, 474542, '29.06.2019'],
  [21091704, 427701, '28.06.2019'],
  [21091704, 427701, '28.06.2019']]]
```

Answer (score 1):

you are decreasing the list size while iterating, so you are getting this issue. Try the below code and check!

```
def zero_clear(tablica):
   count = 0
   while count < len(tablica):
      if tablica[count][1] == 0:
         del tablica[count]
      else:
         count += 1 
   return tablica


for item in tablica:
   zero_clear(item)
print(tablica)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are deleting the items while reading the table. Every time you delete an item, the table is shorter, so you eventually get a `list index out of range` error.

You could do it this way instead:

```
tablica = [[[row for i in range(len(item))] for row in item if row[1] != 0] for item in tablica]
```

Comment: look at my answer please

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `pandas` library:

```
import pandas as pd


new_tablica = []
column_names = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']

for matrix in tablica:
    df = pd.DataFrame(matrix, columns=column_names) 

    df = df[df['col2'] > 0]
    new_tablica.append(df.values.tolist())
```

I haven't tested timings, but this way the solution is easily scalable to large matrices. I recommend you to use the `pandas` library for managing table-like data, as it has lots of methods more efficient than pure Python.

Comment: Hello jcf it looks nice and logic. But do You know why I still have an error in your code?     new_tablica.append(df.values.tolist()) # this way the solution is in the same format as the input
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: I tried this code and didn't got any error. Check if the syntax is correct when you copied the code. I forgot to mention I edited a typo previously, so try it now!

Answer (score 0):

I thing that something went wrong because after your change of the matrix, when I use simple for loops, to see the output it should be like this ( without lists with 0 on second position) :

```
    for ele in tablica:
        for item in ele:
            print(item)

[21091705, 653842, '29.06.2019']
[21091705, 641701, '28.06.2019']
[21091705, 642000, '27.06.2019']
[21091705, 642030, '25.06.2019']
[21091705, 642030, '25.06.2019']
[21091705, 637030, '25.06.2019']
[21091705, 641256, '25.06.2019']
[21091703, 487000, '30.06.2019']
[21091703, 461524, '29.06.2019']
[21091703, 427701, '28.06.2019']
[21091703, 429000, '27.06.2019']
[21091701, 421077, '30.06.2019']
[21091701, 453777, '29.06.2019']
[21091701, 427701, '28.06.2019']
[21091701, 433123, '27.06.2019']
[21091704, 491000, '30.06.2019']
[21091704, 474542, '29.06.2019']
[21091704, 427701, '28.06.2019']
[21091704, 427701, '28.06.2019']
```

When I use this loops to see the output after your change of the matrix the output is much more complicated:

```
tablica = [[[row for i in range(len(item))] for row in item if row[1] != 0] for item in tablica]
```

Output of:

```
for ele in tablica:
      for item in ele:
                print(item)

[[21091705, 653842, '29.06.2019'], [21091705, 653842, '29.06.2019'], [21091705, 653842, '29.06.2019'], [21091705, 653842, '29.06.2019'], [21091705, 653842, '29.06.2019'], [21091705, 653842, '29.06.2019'], [21091705, 653842, '29.06.2019'], [21091705, 653842, '29.06.2019'], [21091705, 653842, '29.06.2019'], [21091705, 653842, '29.06.2019'], [21091705, 653842, '29.06.2019'], [21091705, 653842, '29.06.2019']]
[[21091705, 641701, '28.06.2019'], [21091705, 641701, '28.06.2019'], [21091705, 641701, '28.06.2019'], [21091705, 641701, '28.06.2019'], [21091705, 641701, '28.06.2019'], [21091705, 641701, '28.06.2019'], [21091705, 641701, '28.06.2019'], [21091705, 641701, '28.06.2019'], [21091705, 641701, '28.06.2019'], [21091705, 641701, '28.06.2019'], [21091705, 641701, '28.06.2019'], [21091705, 641701, '28.06.2019']]
[[21091705, 642000, '27.06.2019'], [21091705, 642000, '27.06.2019'], [21091705, 642000, '27.06.2019'], [21091705, 642000, '27.06.2019'], [21091705, 642000, '27.06.2019'], [21091705, 642000, '27.06.2019'], [21091705, 642000, '27.06.2019'], [21091705, 642000, '27.06.2019'], [21091705, 642000, '27.06.2019'], [21091705, 642000, '27.06.2019'], [21091705, 642000, '27.06.2019'], [21091705, 642000, '27.06.2019']]
```